# Django's FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS not working for directories

Tags: python, django, apache, permissions, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to use Django's [`FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS) to set permissions when a user uploads a file. The file itself is created with the correct permissions (`775`), but any directories created seem to be stuck with the default (`755`).

Example: 
If a file (`foo.jpg`) is uploaded for a user (`id = 123`), it should save to `media/123/foo.jpg`, creating the `123` directory if it does not already exist. `foo.jpg` has `775` but `123` has `755`.

How can I get directories saving with the correct permissions? I am using Apache with mod_wsgi in a httpd Docker container if it is relevant.

Comment: Have you considered using `os.chmod` to set the directory permissions on creation? I may not solve the underlying issue, but would be worth looking at.

Comment: @DanielMorell I have, but the actual file saving is happening inside Django, not my own code. I wouldn't know how to overwrite that, but if I could then I would consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has a seperate setting for file directory permisions. It is `FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS`. You should set this as `0o775` in your `settings.py` file.

[`FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#file-upload-directory-permissions)

[File storage API documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/storage/)

Comment: I have no idea how I missed this for so long. Thank you.